# Azure Windows Server 2008 VM unexpectedly shutdown

Tags: azure

This morning our Azure VM running Server 2008 and SQL Server 2008 went offline, and took about 1 hour to restart. The event log shows only:

The system has rebooted without cleanly shutting down first. This error could be caused if the system stopped responding, crashed, or lost power unexpectedly.

and the Azure dashboard says there were no availability incidents during this time (US - West)

Is it safe to believe the Azure dashboard, which implies that Windows crashed? We don't have Azure support (yet).

Answer (score 1):

When this is a production environment I highly recommend you to configure Availability Sets. This document can guide you: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-manage-availability/

Back to your question on trusting the Azure Service Dashboard:

You have one Virtual Machine running on a host in the Azure data center. Now assume this one host would fail, I doubt this will trigger a performance degradation or service interruption alert.

Maybe someone with more background about how the Service Dashboard works can confirm!

However, I do find it strange that it took 1 hour to restart. Could this be SQL Server recovering the database(s)? This should be visible in the Event log.